# Execute animation in loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview

It is very funny situation : 
    NSLog(@"%@", _matrix);

Hi, I am making animation like :

```
NSLog(@"%f %f", item.frame.origin.x, item.frame.origin.y);


[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
    item.frame = currentItemFrame;
}];
NSLog(@"%f %f", item.frame.origin.x, item.frame.origin.y);
```

log result

```
2015-04-02 00:56:52.247 Project15[14543:806921] 49.000000 1.000000
2015-04-02 00:56:52.247 Project15[14543:806921] 1.000000 1.000000
```

so coordinates changed, but , my object wasn't animated. 
It was animated only when for cycle ended, but I need to draw on each iteration. Is there a straight way to do this ?

Comment: Are you doing this in viewDidLoad? If you are, move it to viewWillAppear

Comment: @Chase i am doing this by buttonAction, so there is no viewDidLoad or ViewWilAppear

Comment: What does “when for cycle ended” mean? Do you have a `for` loop around the `animateWithDuration:animations:` call? If so, edit your question to include more code.

Comment: @robmayoff there is a huge code, and I don't think that it will help you.
Execute animation in loop - name of question. So, yes, I want to do an animation in loop, but it executes only after loop.

Comment: please provide your for loop

Comment: @Chase my class is huge, it is bad code, so It won't help me. Imagine that it is simple loop, if you need.

Comment: @user3224534 well I need to know the context. Your animation works. I just tested it... so what it wrong is that the context you are calling it in is incorrect. Depending on the loop and where it is run it will not be in the main thread. All animations MUST run in the main thread. You need to rework your animation to use the completion block like rob pointed out if this is the case.

Comment: @user3224534 try wrapping your animation in a dispatch block **dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
// your animation 
      }); **

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put an animation in a `for` loop. The animation doesn't start until you return control to the main run loop, which doesn't happen until your `for` loop, and any other code in your event handler, finish running.

Instead, you need to use the `animateWithDuration:animations:completion:` method to provide a completion block. The system will run your completion block when the animation finishes. In the block, you can decide to run the animation again, or do something else, or do nothing at all.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand. I cannot do animation on each iteration? Or i cannot do it legal, and there is some way?

Comment: @user3224534 The time stamps in the log results you provide in your question help explain why you need a completion handler. You should observe that the second log statement is executed immediately and does not wait for the animation block to complete.